# named query to fetch result by using IN clause with null or without null conditionally

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, named-query

I need a single named query that fulfills below both named query conditions only by setting the Query parameter.

Named Query, to fetch record where "softwareVersion" is null OR softwareVersion matched with the list.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getIPDetectionDetailsForPanIndia",
            query =  "select cssc.css.sapId,
                             cssc.css.hostName,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.category,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.parameter,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.vendor,
                             cssc.recommendedValue,
                             cssc.actualValue,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.id,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.information,
                             cssc.css.softwareVersion,
                             jioc.name,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.impact,
                             cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.command
                      from CssComplianceDetail cssc
                             join cssc.css c
                             left join c.cluster club
                             left join clus.jiocenter jioc 
                      where cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.impact in (:impactType)
                        and cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.category in (:category)
                        and TO_CHAR(cssc.creationDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = TO_CHAR(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                        and (cssc.css.softwareVersion in (:softwareVersion)
                             or cssc.css.softwareVersion is null)";
```

Named Query, to fatch record where "softwareVersion" matched with the list only, no need to fatch null softwareVersion.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getIPDetectionDetailsForPanIndiaAcceptNull",
            query = "select cssc.css.sapId,
                            cssc.css.hostName,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.category,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.parameter,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.vendor,
                            cssc.recommendedValue,
                            cssc.actualValue,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.id,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.information,
                            cssc.css.softwareVersion,
                            jioc.name,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.impact,
                            cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.command
                     from CssComplianceDetail cssc
                            join cssc.css c
                            left join c.cluster club
                            left join clus.jiocenter join
                     where cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.impact in (:impactType)
                       and cssc.cssGoldenConfiguration.category in (:category)
                       and TO_CHAR(cssc.creationDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = TO_CHAR(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                       and cssc.css.softwareVersion in (:softwareVersion)";
```

Below is my Java code:

```
 List softwareVersion = new ArrayList();

    if(softwareVersion.contains("All")) {
        query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getIPDetectionCountForPanIndiaAcceptNull");
    } else {
        query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getIPDetectionCountForPanIndia");
    }

    query.setParameter("softwareVersion", softwareVersion);
```

Comment: Why don't you go for a Criteria builder API .. tailor made for such situations..

Comment: You can write a case statement in and condition